# Access ComboBox save value

Tags: ms-access

I use a combobox to select value form a query. and make 2 columns in combobox.

```
the list will be

John        1
David       2
Michael     3
```

and expect when I selected John, will save 1 to table. but access save 0 to table, and if select David, will save 1. how can I save to Column 2 value to table?

Comment: That's quite strange. Please make sure that you defined correctly properties of your combobox, for instance like described [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index.php). And make sure that your rowsource query returns correct results.

Comment: I got it, if I put ID in column 1, and name in column 2. everything is fine.